# Remove middle directory in multi-project gradle build

Tags: gradle

In a multi-project build I have a "modules" directory that contains several sub-projects.

Instead of referencing a sub-project `A` via `project(':modules:A')`, I would like to reference it as `project(':A')`.

Is it possible to tell gradle to eliminate the "modules" directory in the project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by manipulating the settings.gradle file. 
you have to manually configure the location of your ":A"  settings.gradle file:

```
project(":A").projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "modules/A")
```

you can also do this more generic by iterating over all subprojects

```
rootProject.children.each {project ->
....
}
```